# jquery - Fancy Product Designer not working on localhost but working on local full path

Tags: jquery

I am working to embed fancy product designer jQuery plugin into my site but when I open on localhost this plugin is not working but when I directly open this file from the destination where it is located on my pc then it is working...

plugin link : - http://fancyproductdesigner.com/
Can anyone suggest why it is working with full local path but not on localhost ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely trying to load resources by injecting script tags, which is normally blocked locally.